# Vector analysis in R

Tags: r, rstudio

As inputs your function should take a vector of 0s and 1s;
Every time you see a sequence of 1s in the data you need to increase the number of children by 1;
Be careful with the two subsequent sequences of 1s, where the difference between them is less than 5 (i.e. when there are less than 5 0s in between them, then it is the same child and not a new child);
To help you social planner provides some examples of what your function should return:

```
#Input: c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)

#Output: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

#Input: c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)

#Output: 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2

#Input: c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1)

#Output: 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
```

Functions, which might be helpful:
`diff()
cumsum()
which()
rle()`

I dont quite understand how to approach the question, my thoughts on this are using diff function after the cumsum as it will help me to sustain a row of 1s but in this scenario i am loosing the length of vector (it obviously becomes shorter) also `#rle$lenght` seems to help me to detect gaps of length 5 or more to turn 1s into 2s. Sorry for this question I am only a beginner

Answer (score 0):

I make use of which function in r (https://www.r-bloggers.com/which-function-in-r/) and run length encoding (http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Finding_sequences_of_identical_values/). Here's my attempt:

```
vector_analyse <- function(sample_vector){
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Signature: vector --> vector
  # Author: kon_u
  # Description: Given a sample vector of 0s and 1s, return a sequence of 1s in 
  # the data you need to increase the number of children by 1 (when there are less 
  # 5 0s in between them, then it is the same child and not a new child)
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Run Length Encoding gives a list of length and values
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  rle_object <- rle(sample_vector)
  x <- rle_object$lengths # original length 
  y <- rle_object$values # original values
  z <- which(y == 1) # index of 1 in vector y
  if (length(z) == 1){
    invisible()
  } else{
    for (i in 2:length(z)){
      if (x[z[i]-1] >= 5){
        y[z[i]] = y[z[i]]
      } else {
        y[z[i]] = y[z[i]] - 1
      }
    }
  }
  y_cumsum = cumsum(y)
  rle_object$values <- y_cumsum
  new_vector = inverse.rle(rle_object)
  return(new_vector)
}

vector_analyse(c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)) # 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
vector_analyse(c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)) # 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
vector_analyse(c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1)) # 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
```